# Change font color of specific cell in a table

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a VBA procedure that loops through the rows of an Excel table and updates cell values:

```
Public Sub LoadRecords()
    Dim n As Long
    With DataSheet.ListObjects(tblName)
        For n = 1 To .ListRows.Count
            If UCase(.ListColumns(colNameLoad).DataBodyRange(n).Value) = "Y" Then
                .ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n) = response
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to enhance the code so that, in addition to updating the cell values, it also changes the cell font colour.

I can do this for the entire column:

```
.ListColumns(colNameMessage).Range.Font.colorIndex = 48
```

However, I can't figure out how to change the font colour of a specific cell/row from within the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close already. `.ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n)` is the individual cell, so:

```
.ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n).Value = response 
.ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n).Font.ColorIndex = 48
```

As mentioned in a (now deleted) comment, it's preferable to use `.Font.Color` instead of `.Font.ColorIndex`, as the latter is just an index in the *current palette*, not an absolute color.

Comment: About using `.Font.Color` instead of `.Font.ColorIndex`: I assume the value for `.Font.Color` would be something like `RGB(0, 0, 0)`. How would I put `RGB(0, 0, 0)` in a constant?

Comment: There's lots of built-in constants already... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrgbcolor... but `RGB(0,0,0)` is just equivalent to `0`.